# Testing Failed when build using Xcode build command or appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am using :

```
Xcode 10.1
Os Version : 12.1
iPhone 6
```

I did follow all required steps to setup build and everything but still getting error when try to build project using xcode build.

I am confuse between 2 thing that is it signing issue or I am missing some config. in webdriver agent xproj.

### Actual Error on xcode build command

```
Testing failed:
WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app encountered an error (Failed to install or launch the test runner. (Underlying error: Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner. (Underlying error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (DTXMessage error 1.))))
```

### Actual Error on appium

```
Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: “xcodebuild failed with code 65”. Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
```

### Some other logs if that helps :

```
2018-11-19 11:02:17.350 xcodebuild[2413:325556] Error Domain=com.apple.platform.iphoneos Code=-12 “Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner” UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8ec758be20 {Error Domain=DTXMessage Code=1 “(null)” UserInfo={DTXExceptionKey=The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user. : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier ‘com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner’}}}
2018-11-19 11:02:17.350 xcodebuild[2413:325556] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=4 “Failed to install or launch the test runner” UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at /Users/asianweb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2018.11.19_11-02-01-+0530.xcresult, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to install or launch the test runner, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8ec7ac6c70 {Error Domain=com.apple.platform.iphoneos Code=-12 “Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner” UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8ec758be20 {Error Domain=DTXMessage Code=1 “(null)” UserInfo={DTXExceptionKey=The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user. : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier ‘com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner’}}}}}
```

### Other logs info

```
{
deviceSerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXX
identifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6
deviceClass: iPhone
deviceName: qa’s iPhone
deviceIdentifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6
productVersion: 12.1
buildVersion: 16B92
deviceSoftwareVersion: 12.1 (16B92)
deviceArchitecture: arm64
deviceTotalCapacity: 11945508864
deviceAvailableCapacity: 5477302272
deviceIsTransient: NO
ignored: NO
deviceIsBusy: NO
deviceIsPaired: YES
deviceIsActivated: YES
deviceActivationState: Activated
isPasscodeLocked: NO
deviceType: <DVTDeviceType:0x8f7ec4d00ca0 Xcode.DeviceType.iPhone>
supportedDeviceFamilies: (
1
)
applications: (null)
provisioningProfiles: (null)
hasInternalSupport: NO
isSupportedOS: YES
developerDiskMountError: (null)
(null)
bootArgs: (null)
connected: yes
isWirelessEnabled: no
connectionType: direct
hostname: (null)
bonjourServiceName: 90:60:f1:6b:7f:91@fe80::9760:f1ff:fe6b:2f92._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.
} (12.1 (16B92))
```

**Note :** While I run it, it puts my app and webdriveragent into iphone device and then stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve issue by following steps :

1. Uninstalled following :

   Xcode,Appium,Xcode command line,ideviceinstaller,carthage,xpretty,deviceconsole
2. Reinstalled everything as per this video guide : https://youtu.be/ySglJIrDVMQ
3. Restart my mac machine and iphone
4. Again setup project in xcode as per this video guide : https://youtu.be/ySglJIrDVMQ
5. And Yes it works.

Comment: This would be a much more helpful answer if you could summarize the video. What was the actual problem, and what's the solution? If the linked video ever disappears, this answer in its current state will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS development I use **Fastlane** with the **XCTest** framework and I had the same problem as you described. However, I'm using a simulator, not a real device. To solve it I replaced **iPhone 6** with **iPhone XS Max** in the list of simulators that should be used for testing. If you can also use any other device different from **iPhone 6** you should try this solution.

However if you need to test your application on **iPhone 6** you can recreate the corresponding simulator. In Xcode 10.1 press **Window** -> **Devices and Simulators**, then select the line called **iPhone 6** and press **Backspace**. After that press **+** in the left bottom corner of window to create a new simulator. You will see this window:

[image: Create a new simulator]

Set all parameters as they are in this screenshot and then press **Create**. After that, try to run your test suite again.